# How to pass an object input and update the data in a single popup using Vue-SweetAlert2

Tags: vue.js, sweetalert2

I'm currently trying to make a popup in which a user is supposed to fill in his or her personal information, as shown in the following code and the attached image.

```
<template>
      <v-btn class="create-button" color="yellow" @click="alertDisplay">Create</v-btn>

    <br/>

    <p>Test result of createCustomer: {{ createdCustomer }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        createdCustomer: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      alertDisplay() {
        const {value: formValues} = await this.$swal.fire({
            title: 'Create private customer',
            html: '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Customer Number">' +
                '<select id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input"> <option value="fi_FI">fi_FI</option> <option value="sv_SE">sv_SE</option> </select>'
                 + 
                '<input id="swal-input3" class="swal2-input" placeholder="regNo">' +
                '<input id="swal-input4" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address">' +
                '<input id="swal-input5" class="swal2-input" placeholder="First Name">' +
                '<input id="swal-input6" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Last Name">'
                ,
            focusConfirm: false,
            preConfirm: () => {
                return [
                    document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input2').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input3').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input4').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input5').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input6').value
                ]
            }
        })
        if (formValues) {
            this.createdCustomer = this.$swal.fire(JSON.stringify(formValues));
            console.log(this.createdCustomer);
        }   
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image: multiple inputs]

This way, I can let the user fill in multiple fields, but I want to store the "Address" in the form of an Object, not just a string.

```
"address": {
    "street": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "country": "string",
    "region": "string",
    "zipCode": "string"
}
```

I managed to change one of the 6 inputs to a "select" type instead of "input" type which just lets users write some text, but when it comes to an object type that consists of multiple strings like above, I don't know how to do it when I need to use HTML and preConfirm parameters.

How can I do it? Is it even possible to store an "address" as an object in the first place?

***[UPDATED]***

What I'm trying to do is to let the user fill in each of "street", "city", "country", "region", "zipCode" individually, shown as the attached image below,

[image]

and store them as an "address" object like the code below

```
"address": {
    "street": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "country": "string",
    "region": "string",
    "zipCode": "string"
}
```

***[UPDATED (Version2]***

v-model not working

```
async alertDisplay() {

        const {value: formValues} = await this.$swal.fire({
            title: 'Create private customer',
            html: '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Customer Number">' +
                '<select id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input"> <option value="fi_FI">fi_FI</option> <option value="sv_SE">sv_SE</option> </select>'
                 + 
                '<input id="swal-input3" class="swal2-input" placeholder="regNo">' +
                '<input v-model="createdCustomer.address.street" id="swal-input4" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address (street)">' +
                '<input v-model="createdCustomer.address.city" id="swal-input5" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address (city)">' +
                '<input v-model="createdCustomer.address.country" id="swal-input6" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address (country)">' +
                '<input v-model="createdCustomer.address.region" id="swal-input7" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address (region)">' +
                '<input v-model="createdCustomer.address.zipCode" id="swal-input8" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Address (zipCode)">' +
                '<input id="swal-input9" class="swal2-input" placeholder="First Name">' +
                '<input id="swal-input10" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Last Name">'
                ,
            focusConfirm: false,
            preConfirm: () => {
                return [
                    document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input2').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input3').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input4').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input5').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input6').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input7').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input8').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input9').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input10').value
                ]    

            }
        })
        if (formValues) {
            this.createdCustomer = formValues;
            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer);
            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer.address');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer.address);
        }   
      }
```

The output

[image]

But I want it to be like

```
Test result of createCustomer: [ "JS1", "fi_FI", "123ABC", {"stackoverflow st 12", "San Francisco", "USA", "California", "12345"}, "Shinichi", "Takagi" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this problem, so I will post an answer on my own.

The root of the problem turned out to be the single line `this.createdCustomer = formValues;` in the part

```
if (formValues) {
            this.createdCustomer = formValues;
            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer);
            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer.address');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer.address);
        }
```

of my original question post.

Because the user inputs were stored as 10 individual primitive data type inputs instead of an object form "address" that contains multiple strings, it was an array of strings that was assigned to `this.createdCustomer` from `formValues`.

In order to solve this problem, I did the following two things.

1. Declare `createdCustomer` in the form of an object
2. Assign each value of formValues one by one, by referring to its index numbers ( ***← this is what I didn't realize for so long***)

As for the first point, I declared the `createdCustomer` as the following.

```
data() {
      return {
        createdCustomer: {
          customerNumber: null,
          locale: null,
          regNo: null,
          address: {
            street: null,
            city: null,
            country: null,
            region: null,
            zipCode: null
          },
          firstName: null,
          lastName: null
        }
      }
    },
```

And regarding the second point, I referred to formValues's indexes one by one like this.

```
if (formValues) {
            //this.createdCustomer = formValues;   // this one line overwrote the entire createdCustomer object, which was the root of the problem
            this.createdCustomer.customerNumber = formValues[0];
            this.createdCustomer.locale = formValues[1];
            this.createdCustomer.regNo = formValues[2];
            this.createdCustomer.address.street = formValues[3];
            this.createdCustomer.address.city = formValues[4];
            this.createdCustomer.address.country = formValues[5];
            this.createdCustomer.address.region = formValues[6];
            this.createdCustomer.address.zipCode = formValues[7];
            this.createdCustomer.firstName = formValues[8];
            this.createdCustomer.lastName = formValues[9];

            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer.address');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer.address);

            console.log('the content of this.createdCustomer.address.street');
            console.log(this.createdCustomer.address.street);

        }
```

And now that the "address" is passed on in the form of an "address" object, and the output is just as expected.

```
Test result of createCustomer: { "customerNumber": "JS1", "locale": "fi_FI", "regNo": "123ABC", "address": { "street": "stackoverflow st 12", "city": "San Francisco", "country": "USA", "region": "California", "zipCode": "12345" }, "firstName": "Shinichi", "lastName": "Takagi" }
```

[image: successful]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-model`. This way, when you change the value in the input, the value of the address object will also change.

```
<input v-model="address.street">
<input v-model="address.city">
<input v-model="address.country">
<input v-model="address.region>
<input v-model="address.zipCode">
```

See this example https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/bo8cfxqz/5/

Reference for `v-model` https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But in that case doesn't it store the input only in regNo? What I'm trying to do is to store the input in 5 smaller pieces. For example, if a user's address is like "stackoverflow street 12, San Francisco, California, USA, 94016", then it's supposed to be stored as an "address" object that consists of "address.street: stackoverflow 12", "address.city: San Francisco", "address.country: USA", "address.region: California", "address.zipCode: 94016".

Comment: It's a bit hard to determine whether the input is a street or a city or a country. You gotta have a data of every street, city or country to be able to accurately chunk an address piece by piece correctly. If you really wanna achieve this easier, you could use google maps' geo location. The user can input their address and then the google maps api will return the address object of the said address.

Comment: I'm not trying to have my program read the address and determine which part is street, city etc. Instead, what I'm trying to do is better explained in the description above, which I updated a few minutes ago. (Notice that now there are multiple text fields for "address", which consists of "Address (street)", "Address (city)", "Address (country)", "Address (region)", "Address (zipCode)")

Comment: If so, then my original answer would be enough. You just have to create a separate model for each text field of course.

Comment: Yeah in a simple example like the JSFiddle you've shown it's pretty straightforward, but what makes tricky here I think is that I'm trying to obtain the user inputs via popup of Vue-Sweetalert2, not just a plain JavaScript code. I pasted the updated version of my code, but as you can see the output is not as expected. Notice that curly braces are gone, which means that the "address" is not stored as an "address" object, which consists of multiple strings "street", "city", "country", "region", "zipCode"

Comment: Is your `createdCustomer` data null?

Comment: It's declared as null, but after filling in user inputs and press the ok button of the pop up, it becomes Test result of createCustomer: [ "JS1", "fi_FI", "123ABC", "stackoverflow st 12", "San Francisco", "USA", "California", "12345", "Shinichi", "Takagi" ], just as shown below the red "close" button of the screenshot which I added in "UPDATED (Version 2)